# WPF Simple animations causing performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, animation

As you can see below, I have a Canvas that allows you to drag around a single Thumb control. With the ProgressBars IsIndeterminate value set to false, the thumb is very responsive as you drag it around, but as soon as you set it to true, the thumb lags behind by a substantial number of frames even for such a simple case. When you add more controls it gets very noticeable.

Setting the Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the issue?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication30.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Canvas>
    <Thumb Width="50"
           Height="50" 
           Canvas.Left="10"
           Canvas.Top="10"
           DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta"/>

    <ProgressBar Width="200"
                 Height="20"
                 IsIndeterminate="True" />
</Canvas>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Timeline), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 1 });
    }

    private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement obj = sender as UIElement;
        Canvas.SetLeft(obj, Canvas.GetLeft(obj) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(obj, Canvas.GetTop(obj) + e.VerticalChange); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not on my machine. Not even with 5 of them bars.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Do you use custom wpf theme or any progresbar style?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that annimated progress bars destroys performance on terminal servers.

Is it just your machine? Are you remoting in and observing this behavior?